# Using credential process for IAM Roles Anywhere in springboot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-iam

I have a use case where I need to access the SNS topic from outside AWS. We planned to use https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/extend-aws-iam-roles-to-workloads-outside-of-aws-with-iam-roles-anywhere/ as it seems to be the right fit

But I'm unable to get this working correctly. I followed the link exactly mentioed above where the contents of .aws/config file are

```
credential_process = ./aws_signing_helper credential-process
    --certificate /path/to/certificate.pem
    --private-key /path/to/private-key.pem
    --trust-anchor-arn <TA_ARN>
    --profile-arn <PROFILE_ARN>
    --role-arn <ExampleS3WriteRole_ARN>
```

But my spring boot application throws an error stating that it could not fetch the credentials to connect to AWS. Kindly assist

Comment: Note: `.aws/config` should be `~/.aws/config`. Is the `aws_signing_helper` script installed correctly? If you run it manually per the instructions, outside of your Spring Boot app, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work when I issue the ./aws_signing_helper command, it generates credentials in JSON format. The spring-boot app expects the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY env variables to set to establish a connection to AWS and that's where it is failing saying unable to load credentials

Comment: When I set the access key and secret manually by using the aws configure command using aws cli, it works as expected

Comment: I can confirm that the folder structure ~/.aws/config

Comment: You included the credential_process command line above. Is that set for the `[default]` profile in `~/.aws/config` or is it a named profile? Are you setting *any* AWS_xxx [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) before running your app? If intending to use the `[default]` profile then you should not need to set any of them. Can you run an awscli command successfully using the same config profile?

Comment: Yes, I can run the credential process and fetch the credentials by running ./aws_signing_helper....., Yes it is the default profile and aws cli working fine

Comment: No, I'm not asking if you can run the `aws_signing_helper` script successfully. I'm asking if you can run the awscli and have it retrieve credentials successfully via the profile that has the configured credential_process.

Comment: For example, if using named profile `fred` then run `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile fred` or if using the default profile then run `aws sts get-caller-identity`. This will test if an AWS SDK client (the awscli in this case) can successfully retrieve credentials. If it can, then your Java app should be able to.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Do you have the AWS CLI command that can get the credentials using the credential process?

Comment: Any awscli command (other than help and --version) against a profile with a credential_process. Use the command that I just suggested that you run: `aws sts get-caller-identity`

Comment: Yes, aws sts get-caller-identity returns the below

{
    "UserId": "<<user id>>",
    "Account": "<<acc no>>",
    "Arn": "<<arn>>"
}

Comment: During the spring boot app start-up, I get this error though

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [io/awspring/cloud/autoconfigure/messaging/SqsAutoConfiguration$SqsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)),

Comment: The credential process is not setting the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in the env variable or the credentials file is the problem

Comment: That credential process doesn't set environment variables afaik. The whole thing relies on the credential retrieval order documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html) and none of providers 1, 2, or 3 yielding credentials hence it tries the 4th provider, which is the shared credentials and config files. Unless your code (or a dependency) has explicitly chosen the [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.html).

Comment: I'm using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain() so it checks for the credentials in the order. We cannot manually set these variables when running code in any production-grade env and the credentials that it provides are temporary. I'm unsure of how to use this process in any environment where the apps are deployed in a docker container

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest thing to do was to create a separate script for the credential_process to target, this isn't necessary I just found it easier.

So create a script along the lines of:

```
#! /bin/bash 
# raw_helper.sh
/path/to/aws_signing_helper credential-process \
  --certificate /path/to/cert.crt \
  --private-key /path/to/key.key \
  --trust-anchor-arn <TA_ARN> \
  --profile-arn <Roles_Anywhere_Profile_ARN> \
  --role-arn <IAM_Role_ARN>
```

The key thing I found is that most places (including AWS documentation) tell you to use the ~/.aws/config file and declare the profile there. This didn't seem to work, but when I added the profile to my ~/.aws/credentials file it did work. Assuming you've created a helper script, this would look like this:

```
# ~/.aws/credentials
[raw_profile]
credential_process = /path/to/raw_helper.sh
```